# parsing regex csv with quotes as strings and non quotes as numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out a way to parse this CSV with the following entry:

```
"So, can't believe someone, made this comma format", 77777, 3, 2, "the customer thought that this is "so brilliant!" to do."
```

The quotes represents strings and non-quotes represents integers.  What makes this even more complex is there can be nested quotes and commas inside for the string.  Is there a way to parse this and if so what would be the regex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Find out the exact *format* of CSV being used -- e.g. where did it originate, Excel? Once that is discovered the rest will fall into place (hopefully by finding a library that supports said format and not trying to do something ridiculous -- and quite possibly a little brain-dead -- like using a regular expression).

Comment: I suggest you using a CSV reader/writer library, depending on the programming language you're using. If it is C#, you can take a look at LINQ to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to identify all the separator commas. But since you didn't say what programming language you are using so here is the one for Java:

`(?:[0-9\"])[ ]*,[ ]*(?:[0-9\"])`

It simply find comma that surround by either number or quote.
Hope this help.

Comment: `code`
    public class App {
 private static final String  test = "\"So, can't believe someone, made this comma format\", 77777, 3, 2, \"the customer thought that this is \"so brilliant!\" to do.\"";
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] split = test.split("(?:[0-9\"])[ ]*,[ ]*(?:[0-9\"])");
  for(String val:split){
   System.out.println(val);
  }
 }
    }
`code`
result:
`code`
    "So, can't believe someone, made this comma format
    777
    , 
    the customer thought that this is "so brilliant!" to do."
`code`

Comment: errr, format:
    public class App {
     private static final String  test = "\"So, can't believe someone, made this comma format\", 77777, 3, 2, \"the customer thought that this is \"so brilliant!\" to do.\"";
     public static void main(String[] args) {
      String[] split = test.split("(?:[0-9\"])[ ]*,[ ]*(?:[0-9\"])");
      for(String val:split){
       System.out.println(val);
      }
     }
    }
result:

    "So, can't believe someone, made this comma format
    777
    , 
    the customer thought that this is "so brilliant!" to do."

Comment: your regex is very close but it's not picking up the 3, 2,

Comment: @user742746 Then you should post it as an answer and auto-accept it.